# Check if series of images exists, stop when not found in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, same-origin-policy

I'd like to show series of dynamically loaded images named in a structured way in my website. Images are located in a different domain which causes `Same Origin Policy` restriction. I cannot use `$.ajax`.

I build my url like with a counter such as `www.example.com/Images/img-1.jpg`, `www.example.com/Images/img-2.jpg` and it goes...

I've tried several other answers from similar posts but couldn't make them work. Either the loop runs forever or it never finds the images even though they exist in the path.

**1st try:**

```
ShowImages: function () {   
    var urlBase = 'http://www.example.com/Images/img-';
    var i = 1;

    while (true) {
        var url = urlBase + i + '.jpg';     

        var imgDom = new Image();
        imgDom.onload = function () {
            alert('worked');
            i++;
        };
        imgDom.onerror = function () {
            return; // I want to either break the while loop, or return from ShowImages function
        };
        imgDom.src = url;
    }
},
```

It never hits the `.onerror`.

**2nd try:**

```
ShowImages: function () {   
    var urlBase = 'http://www.example.com/Images/img-';
    var i = 1;

    while (true) {
        var url = urlBase + i + '.jpg';     

        var imgDom = document.createElement("img");
        $(imgDom).attr('src', url);

        if (imgDom.complete) {
            alert('worked');
            i++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
},
```

It never hits the `.complete`.

Comment: You need to try to load the next image only after you have handled the previous one. Image loading is asynchronous and your code will actually make a bunch of requests to url `'http://www.example.com/Images/img-1.jpg'`.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of it but was unable to find the way, accomplished it with @gurvinder372 's method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying with your first option (you basically need to chain them)

```
ShowImages(1);
ShowImages: function (counter) {   
    var urlBase = 'http://www.example.com/Images/img-';

        var url = urlBase + counter + '.jpg';     

        var imgDom = new Image();
        imgDom.onload = function () {
            alert('worked');
            ShowImages(counter+1);
        };
        imgDom.onerror = function () {
            alert("all images done..");
            return; // I want to either break the while loop, or return from ShowImages function
        };
        imgDom.src = url;
};
```